# Script will run outside of a function but not within it.

Tags: php

I need to repeat a small piece of code several times so wrote a function which does not work, but when written outside of a function the code does work.  I'm doing something daft but just can't see what it is!! Can someone please tell me how daft I am.  Thank you.

This does not work:

```
function listfiles()
{$count=count($file);
for($z=0; $z<$count; $z++)
{$parts=explode("/",$file[$z]);
$parts=explode(".",$parts[1]);
print"<a href='$file[$z]'>$parts[0]</a><br><br>";}}

$file=glob("/xxx/xxx/files/*.*");
listfiles();
```

Yet this does:

```
$file=glob("/xxx/xxx/files/*.*");
{$count=count($file);
for($z=0; $z<$count; $z++)
{$parts=explode("/",$file[$z]);
$parts=explode(".",$parts[1]);
print"<a href='$file[$z]'>$parts[0]</a><br><br>";}}
```

Comment: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: place the `$file=glob("/xxx/xxx/files/*.*");` inside the function

Comment: Your code is formatted in a way that makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Grumpy, I apologise for my unconventional style.  I began learning to code with Fortran in 1967.  It wasn’t until

Comment: Grumpy, It wasn't until 1982 that I could afford a computer and switched to IBM basic.  Wrote some commercial stuff but coding has only ever been a self taught hobby.  Switched to php when I retired and was asked to build a website.  So apologies again for my style, old habits die hard and at 67 it's old dogs and new tricks !!

Comment: Fred -ii-, Thank you for the link, very helpful.  Always good to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Give the $file variable as an argument

```
function listfiles($file)
{
    $count=count($file);
    for($z=0; $z<$count; $z++)
    {
        $parts=explode("/",$file[$z]);
        $parts=explode(".",$parts[1]);
        print"<a href='$file[$z]'>$parts[0]</a><br><br>";
    }
}

$file=glob("/xxx/xxx/files/*.*");
listfiles($file);
```

Comment: Saphyra.  Thank you so much for this.